jenkins pipeline build parameterized build button missing
We just rolled out a new Jenkins environment and the parameterized button doens't display in new pipeline creation, but it does in our old environment.
New version is 2.426.1.  Old version is 2.401.3
I saw this by simply clicking new item, then pipeline.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

It looks like our new environment was cloned off the old environment and there was some corruption in the pipeline plugin.  Apparently, reinstalling the pipeline plugin resolved the issue and now all of the usual checkboxes (like parameterized...) are now available.

It looks like our new environment was cloned off the old environment and there was some corruption in the pipeline plugin.  Apparently, reinstalling the pipeline plugin resolved the issue and now all of the usual checkboxes (like parameterized...) are now available.
